# What do I need to fire proof a room added onto a mobile home?

Tags: fireproof

I have a mobile home. I poured a concrete pad to put an addition on it. I have wood studded walls, metal roof and siding. I'm putting a wood furnace in this addition. My insurance company says it has to be fire proof with more than just drywall. What else will I have to use?

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33169/potbelly-stove-standing-on-hardwood-floor-directly/33198#33198

Comment: Ask your insurance company what they require. From a building code standpoint, additions to mobile homes are ambiguous because legally a mobile home is a vehicle not a structure

Answer (score 1):

Follow the stove manufacturer's instructions for clearances. It will tell you the fire rating requirements expressed in "hours" (or material type) for surfaces around the stove depending on clearance.

2 layers of 5/8" Type-X fire-rated gypsum board (drywall) gives a 2-hour fire rating to a 16" on-center wood stud wall. Surface treatments like stone, brick, tile, durock, sheet metal, etc., will give you aesthetic options. Check with your local code enforcement authority, they will give you information on local requirements. If you follow manufacturer instructions and local code then your insurance company will accept that if you show them.