# Wood Stove Chiminey Clearance

Tags: woodstove

How much clearance do I need between a wood stove chiminey and the living room wall?

I want to install an antique pot belly stove in the corner of my living room. I'm thinking of attaching concrete backer board to the existing sheet rock and covering that with a brick veneer. If I use a single wall pipe (don't want to loose the heat ), how far away from the veneer does the chimney need to be? What if I use a double walled chimney?

Comment: Check if the stove has a manual online. It will give you information similar to this: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/33169/potbelly-stove-standing-on-hardwood-floor-directly/33198#33198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **NFPA 211 Standard for Chimneys, Fireplaces, Vents, and Solid Fuel-Burning Appliances**, you'll start with 36" clearance all the way around.

> [image: Figure 12.6.2.1(b)]

Then you can use one of the methods described, to reduce the required clearance.

> [image: Table 12.6.2.1]

Or you can follow the manufacturers installation instructions, which for a listed and labeled device supersede the code requirements.

---

As for the connector, you'll start with 18".

> [image: Table 9.5.1.1]

Then apply any reductions.

> [image: Table 9.5.1.2]